# Can I remove my friends' "likes" from my news feed when it is sorted by "most recent"?

Tags: facebook

"Viewing most recent stories" is my default news feed. Is it possible to make it stop showing my friends' "likes", either for specific people or for everybody?

(Note that this variations of this feature have come and gone over the years. Please be sure answers are for today's UI.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way natively to do this. All other variations involve third party extensions which are out of scope for this site.